# Why does the Snowflake PUT command throw error 253003?

Tags: command, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, put

Using snowflake-connector-python 2.4.3, we're able to connect and execute DML & DDL successfully. But the `put` command throws this error:

```
snowflake.connector.errors.OperationalError: 253003: 
253003: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2dbd5784a8>: 
Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known, file=/tmp/tmpwh9m7__x, real file=/tmp/tmpwh9m7__x
```

We can manually `put` files to the specified stage using SnowSQL client. Does the `put` command create its own connection separate from the connection & cursor we've already created in python? Does `put` require a specific outbound port opened through our firewall? I assumed everything is going through port 443 (https).

Comment: Please share more of your code so we can reproduce. The Python connector supports PUT. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-example.html#copying-data-from-an-internal-location

Comment: This error actually appears to be on the reference to the local file.  I assume the file you are trying to put exists on the python host?  Might want to double-check the reference to that file.

Answer (score 0):

I’m also facing same error in Linux with specific user. Trying to figure it out, why snowflake put not able to use the tmp location as user has full access on that tmp dir.

By the way, if I use any other uses, I’m able to complete this task.  So please check if the user has right permissions.

Comment: At least, for me it did the trick. Someone modified the default permissions by using the umask command. After restoring that , I was able to run the jobs successfully. May be, your scenario might be different.